# Moving chatter free users to community licensed users

Tags: community

I have asked a similar question before and the answer works 100%. 
[How can I move chatter free users to Community users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-can-i-move-chatter-free-users-to-community-users/)

I should have spoken about more details before. In our community implementation we use the `contact` associated to the user for some information and some other `related objects` in the `VF tabs/pages` we have.

Since the `contactId` field on the user object is not `"updateable"`, is there any other way to move the `chatter free users` to the `community license` and also have a `contact` associated to it?